# Memcached client library for windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, memcached

I wanted to use memcached for my C++ application. To do that I need a client library, similar for example to `mysqlclient`.

However I'm having a really hard time finding something suitable. Everything seems to be linux only and while some claim to be compatible with windows they require cygwin and other things that I would really like to avoid.

So what I'm looking for is either a pre-compiled windows library (would be best) with the header files, or something I can easily compile natively with Visual Studio.

If there is nothing like that do you think it would be a bad idea if I were to write it myself? The protocol seems pretty trivial and I would really need only the basic commands (set/get, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this one?
http://code.jellycan.com/memcacheclient/

It claims to be primarily for Windows.  Hasn't been updated in a while, but maybe it will work fine for you, and in case it doesn't, probably better to base your own work on it rather than starting from scratch.